# Python Flask - Session Not Being Set with Waitress

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, waitress

I am using waitress on IIS with Flask.

I have a route that sets a session as follows

```
@gp_clinicals_bp.route("/setting", methods=["POST","GET"])
def gp_clinicals():
    session["gp_clinicals_meds_repeat"] = "123456"
    return session["gp_clinicals_meds_repeat"]
```

This returns, unsurprisingly:

```
123456
```

I have another route as follows:

```
@gp_clinicals_bp.route("/testing", methods=["POST","GET"])
def gp_clinicals_test():
    return session["gp_clinicals_meds_repeat"]
```

Now, I get nothing back and the following in the error log

```
2022-08-02 20:03:51,126 - ERROR - app.py - log_exception - 1455 - Exception on /gp-clinicals/medication-repeat [GET]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2077, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1525, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1523, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1509, in dispatch_request
    return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**req.view_args)
  File "E:\Apps\dev\digital\gp_clinicals\gp_clinicals.py", line 158, in gp_clinicals_medication_repeat
    return str(session["gp_clinicals_meds_repeat"])
KeyError: 'gp_clinicals_meds_repeat'
2022-08-02 20:03:51,128 - ERROR - __init__.py - handle_error_500 - 92 - 500 Internal Server Error: The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application.
```

I'm the only one on the server. Below is a snippet from my initilisation file:

```
"""Initialize Flask app."""
import logging
import os
from logging.handlers import RotatingFileHandler
from flask import Flask, render_template, flash,request
from flask_session import Session
from flask_assets import Environment

from config import Config

if Config.FLASK_ENV == "development" and Config.DD_SERVICE:
    patch_all()

sess = Session()

def init_app():
    """Create Flask application."""
    app = Flask(__name__, instance_relative_config=False)
    app.config["CACHE_TYPE"] = "null"
    app.config['SEND_FILE_MAX_AGE_DEFAULT'] = 0
    app.config['TEMPLATES_AUTO_RELOAD'] = True
    app.config["SESSION_TYPE"] = "filesystem"
    app.config.from_object("config.Config")
    assets = Environment()
    assets.init_app(app)
    sess.init_app(app)
```

What's going wrong? In the **flask_session** folder I am seeing files being created

[image]

Any advice? I tried using single apostophes instead of quotes but no go there either

The site in [IIS is running through a reverse proxy in IIS](https://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/creating-a-reverse-proxy-with-url-rewrite-for-iis) - could that be doing it?